# Can I mount my 125 amp service on the exterior wall of the bathroom which means my feeders will be coming in the bathroom wall

Tags: electrical, walls, exterior

125 amp service installation mounted on bathroom exterior wall plumbing is on opposite wall and west of panel wall

Comment: It sounds like the service is already mounted there. Is the question about bringing cabling directly into the wall vs running conduit down the wall to enter into the basement/crawlspace then go from there? Please [edit] your question to include more details.

Comment: Do you mean there will be a bathroom on the other side of the wall from the panel?

Answer (score 3):

The panel can be on the exterior, no problem with that or the conductors going to different rooms through the walls. The service panel can not be in the bathroom or a closet, other than that not many restrictions.

Comment: Yup.  Well, working space - the 30x36" area in front of the panel needs to be kept clear at all times.  So it is preferable to have it in a threshold or hallway, so people will naturally keep that area clear since it's a passage.

Comment: Right now there a service pole outside of the bathroom I wanted to get rid of the pole and mount a new service on the outside of the house but that’s where the bathroom is the service is fed from overhead it’s a new building and I still have to feed that building from the service (residential)

Comment: Any windows? If you bring the mast from the roof it can be done but it can not block the window. the window position& size may need to be adjusted. After a main breaker you can run non metallic cables through the walls to the location you want the service panel. If that is not the service panel. The panel can be on the outside even if plumbing is in that wall. However the panel can not be inside the bathroom or in a storage/clothes closet. If there is not a main breaker the feeders from the meter must be in conduit. Code in most locations requires outside disconnect make it a breaker easy then